# How do I make my form scrollable in Android?

Tags: android

I am new to android. I have drawn a pie chart, and when I see it vertically, it's okay. When I change the view to horizontal, I just get the first half of the chart. I want to be able to scroll down. How do I implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ScrollView. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html